# Set soft navigation key background color for Nougat 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat, softkeys

I want to change background color for navigation soft keys that are introduced for Nougat. Is there any way I can implement that? 
What I already implemented is added navigation bar color in both of my style files. But it's not fixing this and I don't see any changes.

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navColor</item>
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding this to your styles:
`<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>`

Comment: Or use this in your main activity:
 `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    }`

Comment: @tonakriz : none of your suggestion works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding these to v21/styles

```
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
```

and defined this in normal styles.xml file

```
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

`colorAccent` is the accent color I defined for the app

I'm answering this question in case someone might be having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.MYCOLOR);
        window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.MYCOLOR);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @vaishakh I already solved it though. not this way but though styles. this is programmatic fix but styles seems to be better approach to this